# React Hooks useEffect Change Fetch URL Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I'm new to hooks and I have this project (`https://thereacttimes.netlify.app/`) and it uses the New York Times API to display stories from different news sections.

I created a masthead of section titles. If you click "arts" it will change the URL to `https://thereacttimes.netlify.app/arts` but I need to use that section title as the fetch URL param and I'm not sure how to re-render/re-fetch with my useEffect Hook. The fetch URL allows us to pass the `section` like this to fetch different stories: `fetch("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/{section}.json?api-key=4fzCTy6buRI5xtOkZzqo4FfEkzUVAJdr)`.

If you're asking yourself why its working in production now, its because I hard-coded the URL to work as: `fetch("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=4fzCTy6buRI5xtOkZzqo4FfEkzUVAJdr)`

What do I change in my useEffect hook?
What do I add to the buttons in my masthead component to call the re-render?

**News Component**

```js
export default function News() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [stories, setStory] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`"https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/{section}.json?api-key=""`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTimeout(() => setStory(data), 1500);
        console.log("Success ", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!stories) {
    return <LoadingBar type={"cylon"} color={"#193152"} />;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <ul className="stories">
          {stories.results.map((story) => {
            return (
              <Story
                title={story.title}
                abstract={story.abstract}
                img={story.multimedia[0].url}
                alt={story.multimedia[0].caption}
                link={story.url}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <Spacer height={100} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Masthead Component**

```js
import React from "react";
import uuid from "uuid";

var sections = [
  "arts",
  "business",
  "fashion",
  "health",
  "movies",
  "opinion",
  "politics",
  "science",
  "sports",
  "technology",
];

export default function Masthead() {
  return (
    <div className="masthead">
      {sections.map((section) => {
        return (
          <a href={section} key={uuid}>
            <span>{section}</span>
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your url in fetch be `\`https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${section}.json?api-key=${apiKey}\`` ?
Also, how are you planning to pass `section` to your url?

Comment: it works fine hard coded, but regardless sure, I can take it out. that part is not what i'm having trouble with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would need to understand the larger context of your app of course to come up with a more elegant solution, but just a cursory look at what you have provided suggests using something as simple as this:

```
const getCurrentPage = () => {
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  const page = url.pathname.split('/').pop();
  return page ? page: 'home';
}

export default function News() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [stories, setStory] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const section = getCurrentPage();
    fetch(`https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${section}.json?api-key=4fzCTy6buRI5xtOkZzqo4FfEkzUVAJdr`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTimeout(() => setStory(data), 1500);
        console.log("Success ", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  }, []);
...
...
```

Nice touch on The React Times by the way.

Comment: holy cow, that was way simpler than I imagined. works perfectly. also, you helped me the other day with my setTimeout/async question. i really appreciate it! and thanks, i thought react times was fairly creative!

Comment: This is not a good way to solve this question. Better to use dependency in use effect, and get  the section parameter using routing.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I completely agree. If he had something like react routing in place, the solution would certainly be more elegant.

Comment: @SuleymanSah can you explain why? I'm testing it now and it's working perfectly for me. What are we not considering?

Comment: @Christian it may work, but not a good solution in react best practices. I advise you to learn useeffect dependencies and routing to improve your knowledge  of react.

Comment: @Christian He is not arguing that it works. He is only saying that you should get proper routing in place, which would require more than superficial changes to your app, but would also allow you to solve problems like this more easily.

Comment: @Christian in you app, do you notice the page refresh, in single page applications (SPA) this is not desired, if you check my codesandbox, you will see no page refresh.

Comment: okay thanks all, i just realized not all sections have images so now I'll implement the react router solution, but figure out "optional props"

Answer (score 3):

To be able to rerender the News component when the section changes, you need to add section to the dependency list in the useeffect like [section].

By the way there is no section variable in the News component, I guess what you are trying to do is pass a section parameter to the News component, if so you had better to use [routing](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start), and pass the section parameter to the News component.

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-meitner-71r8b) with some other changes and refactoring:

Comment: @Christian what do you think about this answer. Please see the codesandbox.

Comment: BTW, I love this. But I don't know if he would be willing to wrap this app into the context of react-router. +1 from me.

Comment: @codemonkey thank you.  If there is some navigation in an app, we have to use routing anyway.

Comment: hey @SuleymanSah, i tried implementing it but it didn't work. Can I email you about it?

Comment: @Christian I think you can apply my solution in the codesandbox to your app. Check the codesandbox please.

Comment: I did. I got this error after implementing your code: "There are three common reasons you might be seeing it: You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app." That's rather vague and not sure how to debug.

Comment: Please search this error in google and try to fix yourself, this will make you a better developer.